# unable to load rules while testing snort in test mode on windows8

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

i installed snort and while running it following error appeared on windows8

```
    --== Initializing Snort ==--
```

Initializing Output Plugins!
Initializing Preprocessors!
Initializing Plug-ins!
Parsing Rules file "c:\snort\etc\snort.conf"
ERROR: c:\snort\etc\snort.conf(51) Missing argument to DNS_SERVERS
Fatal Error, Quitting..
Could not create the registry key.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is probably that you do not have anything defined in DNS_SERVERS variable in your snort.conf file.

Please post your C:\snort\etc\snort.conf file, but I suspect if you edit the line that probably says:

```
ipvar DNS_SERVERS
```

to something like

```
ipvar DNS_SERVERS $HOME_NET
```

It will work, or at least it will get further along your initialization process